# How to connect via WebSocket on Android using Scarlet?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, websocket, client

Code from README.md

```
 val scarletInstance = Scarlet.Builder()
    .webSocketFactory(okHttpClient.newWebSocketFactory(GDAX_URL))
    .addMessageAdapterFactory(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory())
    .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

Version and dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.8'
implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-websocket-okhttp:0.1.7"
implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-stream-adapter-rxjava2:0.2.4"
implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-message-adapter-moshi:0.2.4"
implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-lifecycle-android:0.2.4"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should declare a WebSocket client using an interface. Use Scarlet annotations such as `@Receive` and `@Send` to define how you are going to handle the WebSocket communication, as the following example:

```
interface NewsService {
    @Receive
    fun observeWebSocketEvent(): Flowable<WebSocket.Event>
    @Send
    fun sendSubscribe(subscribe: Subscribe)
    @Receive
    fun observeNews(): Flowable<MyNews>
}
```

Next step is create an implementation of your Scarlet Interface and subscribe the data stream emitted during the WebSocket connection. In the following example , Moshi and RxJava are being used however Scarlet provide other ways to handle and manipulate the data.

```
val scarletInstance = Scarlet.Builder()
    .webSocketFactory(okHttpClient.newWebSocketFactory(BASE_URL))
    .addMessageAdapterFactory(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory())
    .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapter.Factory())
    .build()

//service created
val newsService = scarletInstance.create<NewsService>()

//define websocket event observer
newsService.observeWebSocketEvent()
    .filter { it is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened<*> }
    .subscribe({
        newsService.sendSubscribe()
    })

// news data result
newsService.observeNews()
    .subscribe({ news ->
        Log.d(TAG, news.toString())
    })
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, How to close the connection.

Comment: For closing connection create a lifecycle e.g. 
`var myLifecycle = CustomSocketLifecycle()`
 where 
`class CustomSocketLifecycle(
        val lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry()
) : Lifecycle by lifecycleRegistry {
    init {
        lifecycleRegistry.onNext(Lifecycle.State.Started)
    }
}`

for start listening use `myLifecycle.lifecycleRegistry.onNext(Lifecycle.State.Started)`
and stop listening use `myLifecycle.lifecycleRegistry.onNext(Lifecycle.State.Stopped.WithReason(ShutdownReason.GRACEFUL))`

Comment: How to do this without RxJava but with live data

Comment: You should think about Kotlin.Flow for that

Answer (score 4):

Your code is FAILING due to class duplication. It occurs because of different lib versions. The correct implementation is:

```
//web sockets
implementation 'com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.10'
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:websocket-okhttp:0.1.10"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:stream-adapter-rxjava2:0.1.10"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:message-adapter-moshi:0.1.10"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:lifecycle-android:0.1.10"
```