# Data update in RecyclerView from Scarlet web socket library coroutine not working after back button pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, rx-java2, android-lifecycle

I am new to android development and trying to implement a Scarlet library for receiving messages from the server for a chat application. The socket connection has been established and is able to receive messages from the server.

Here is the scenario for an explanation of the issue:

- Everything works fine when the chat screen opens up for the first
  time.
- But when the back button is pressed and if the user opens the chat
  screen again, then this time the recycler view is getting null and
  app crashes.

Here is the code that I am using currently in fragment:

```
val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val socketBaseURL = "wss://example.com/ws"
    val backoffStrategy = ExponentialWithJitterBackoffStrategy(5000, 5000)

chatService =  Scarlet.Builder()
            .webSocketFactory(okHttpClient.newWebSocketFactory(socketBaseURL))
            .addMessageAdapterFactory(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory())
            .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
            .backoffStrategy(backoffStrategy)
            .lifecycle(AndroidLifecycle.ofLifecycleOwnerForeground(moneoApp, this))
            .build()
            .create<ChatService>()



val authentication = SocketAuthentication(
        type = "authentication",
        content = AuthService().getAuth(userToken)
)

chatService?.observeWebSocketEvent()
        ?.filter { it is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened<*> }
        ?.subscribe ({
            // authenticate with socket server if connection is open
            chatService?.authenticateSocket(authentication)
        }, {error ->
            Log.e("Socket connection", "Error while observing socket ${error.cause}")
        })
```

Here is the block of code that is causing an issue.

```
// start receiving messages from socket server
chatService?.observeIncomingMessage()
        ?.subscribe ({ message ->
            println(message) // no issue at all
            job = GlobalScope.launch { // this part is creating an issue, tried with CoroutineScope also not working
                reloadData(message)
            }
        }, { error ->
            Log.e("Observe message", "Error while observing message ${error.cause}")
        })
```

Actually, the instance of the UI is being captured inside the subscribe block and subscribe is not being destroyed even when I press the back button. So when I press the back button and open chat screen again, the recyclerview is null as the subcribe block is trying to use the previous recyclerview that is already destroyed when pressed back button.

```
    // App Crashes with recyclerview null issue
suspend fun reloadData(message: MessageBody){
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            chatMessageList.add(message.content)
            chatRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            chatRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatMessageList.size - 1)
        }
    }
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        job?.cancel()
    }
```

I have searched through the internet and spent lots of time to get a solution but with no success.
Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: why do you start a coroutine in the subscribe lambda, how does it provide anything useful over just calling a method?

Comment: Well I have to update recyclerview in main thread after I receive message from websocket, if i do not update recyclerview in main thread the app crashes.

Comment: Is this chain a rxchain? If so update on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` or use a `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` and dispose of the chain correctly - you seem to be over complicating subscribing to one chain and having to manage state of the subscriber.

Comment: @MarkKeen I used this official tutorial from Scarlet https://medium.com/tinder-engineering/taming-websocket-with-scarlet-f01125427677 where subscribe is used to receive data from socket and yes its a rxchain.

Comment: Thats a blog post?

Comment: @MarkKeen yes its a blog post mentioned in Scarlet github https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet

Comment: And that states using coroutines in the subscriber like you have - where your issue is?

Comment: @MarkKeen Actually, still I am not sure if its caused by coroutine or rxchain subscribe. The problem is, the first time I open chat screen everything works fine and recyclerview gets updated when new message is received. But when I press back button and again open chat screen the problem occurs. The app crashes with recyclerview being null warning. It seems chatService is not getting newly instatiated and not using current recyclerview object. It is using old recyclerview which is destroyed when back button pressed. Dont know why subscribe is not using newly instantiated recyclerview.

Comment: After spending lots of time, finally found the solution. Actually, I have to close the socket connection as mentioned here in one of the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847644/how-to-connect-via-websocket-on-android-using-scarlet